# webdriver can't find element on UI

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I'm trying to test search UI using selenium web driver in java
If I click on result it shows some properties of that results.
So now when I click on first result, the webdriver is able to locate those properties by `FindElementsByXpath("//li[@class='clickable ng-binding ng-scope']")`
Also tried `findElementsByCss("*[class='clickable ng-binding ng-scope']")`
But when webdriver clicks on second result, it shows up their properties but webdriver is UNABLE to locate properties (have same class name as first).

Any help here?
can't use Xpath since ids are unique and different.
[image: First result clicked]

---

[image: Second result clicked]

i click result using this-

```
findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/els-result["+num+"]/div")).click();
```

where `num` is result number
*Stack trace here

> org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Expected condition failed: waiting for visibility of all elements located by By.cssSelector: *[class='clickable ng-binding ng-scope'] (tried for 15 second(s) with 500 MILLISECONDS interval)
>   Build info: version: '3.1.0', revision: '86a5d70', time: '2017-02-16 07:57:44 -0800'
>   System info: host: '', ip: '', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.12.3', java.version: '1.8.0_121'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{rotatable=false, raisesAccessibilityExceptions=false, marionette=true, appBuildId=20170125094131, version=, platform=MAC, proxy={}, command_id=1, specificationLevel=0, acceptSslCerts=false, processId=22487, browserVersion=51.0.1, platformVersion=16.4.0, XULappId={ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}, browserName=firefox, takesScreenshot=true, takesElementScreenshot=true, platformName=darwin, firefox_profile=UEsDBBQACAgIAOl6aUoAAAAAAAAAA..., unexpectedAlertBehaviour=dismiss}]
>   Session ID: df2df541-1966-5a4b-871c-7cd8c295f4eb
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait.timeoutException(WebDriverWait.java:80)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.FluentWait.until(FluentWait.java:257)
>       at cucumber.stepdefination.DataSearch.FindElementsByCss(DataSearch.java:166)
>       at cucumber.stepdefination.AssestCountSD.assest_count_matches_list(AssestCountSD.java:76)
>       at cucumber.stepdefination.AssestCountSD.for_each_source_assest_count_matches_that_in_list_on_right(AssestCountSD.java:51)
>       at ✽.Then For each source assest count matches that in list on right(/Users/malikh/Documents/workspace/cucumber/src/test/resource/assetCount.feature:6)

Comment: what about `FindElementsByCss(".clickable.ng-binding.ng-scope")`

Comment: @eLRuLL this is also giving timeout error. This also worked for first result but didn't for second result

Comment: the site is changing then, the element is not available the second time.

Comment: @eLRuLL Nope. site doesn't change, first result shrink and second result maximize to accommodate properties. I'll add screenshot if that helps

Comment: Screenshot + HTML would help

Comment: @Dillanm added HTML too

Comment: Share code you use to click `first and second results` and exception log

Comment: @Andersson added that too

Comment: can you change `FindElementsByCss` to `FindElementByCss` and try ?

Comment: if your requirement is to click Description then you can use xpath like `//div[@class='asset-list']/ul/li[normalize-space()='Description'] `

Comment: @NarendraRajput i need to get content of all elements below `Descript‌​ion` and they are with same class name so its going to returns list of elements, thats why used `FindElementsByCss`

Comment: ok i miss understood your question , can u add some code snippet what you have tried ?

Comment: @NarendraRajput `FindElementsByXpath("//li[@class='clickable ng-binding ng-scope']")`

Comment: @All    I have found a way around - that is to refresh page every time before clicking next result. It is able to locate elements then BUT refresh is an overhead and takes up a lot of time. Any idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Firefox browser and install one of its extensions called 'Firepath'. This would help you to locate a UI element using both 'Xpath' and  'CSS'.